# How to properly add content after a div with position absolute

Tags: html, css

The code I have is:

```
<div style="position: relative; clear: both;">
<img src="/b_doodles/banner.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; position: absolute;">
<img src="/b_doodles/profile-pic.png" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; position: absolute; top: 30px;">
</div>
This text is not being displayed
```

What I've tried:

```
<div style="position: relative; clear: both;">
<img src="/b_doodles/default-banner.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; position: absolute;">
<img src="/b_doodles/default-profile-pic.png" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; position: absolute; top: 30px;">
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style="position: absolute;">
This text is being displayed
</div>
```

This code is for getting two images on top of each other and text after the images (next line).

That kind of works, but I don't think it is really a good idea. Please help.

Comment: I think you don't yet understand the CSS visual formatting model. Please read-up on how absolute positioning works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter a fixed height in the first div.